# Delete first 200 columns of my NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have a NumPy array (2700, 83800) but first 200 columns consists of 0 values and I want to delete this part. I mean, if this is my array:

```
x = [[0,0,0, ... ,0,a1,b1,c1, ...],
     [0,0,0, ... ,0,a2,b2,c2, ...],
                  .
                  .
                  .
     [0,0,0, ... ,0,a2700,b2700,c2700, ...]]
```

I want to reshape as

```
x = [[a1,b1,c1, ...],
     [a2,b2,c2, ...],
            .
            .
            .
     [a2700,b2700,c2700, ...]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: do   
"x = x[:, 200:]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]])

a_del = (np.delete(x, np.s_[0:200], 1))

print(a_del)
```

In your case, replace np.array with your array and it works!!

Comment: just replace np.array with yours and all hunky dory!

Answer (score 3):

```
x = x[:,200:]
```

Should do the trick